# Download from github using curl and batch file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, curl, github

I'm currently writing a script in which I need to download the latest version of yt-dlp.exe from Github.
Since the script will need to work on multiple machines, I opted to use curl as the downloader.
I found this script on some other site which I adapted for the program I need.

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ('curl -ks https://api.github.com/repos/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest ^| find "browser_download_url"') do (curl -kOL %%B)
```

Only problem is that it fetches the entire latest release set when I need just one file!
Is there a better way to do this without using powershell?

Thanks!

Comment: Please define better how to distinguish this one file from the others.

Comment: That's a bit the problem right now as after a sleepless night, my brain can't seem to figure this one out. I'm thinking of using a loop to do the work but I feel there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there might be better ways to get the latest **yt-dlp** version...

To answer your question, you simply need to modify the script to look for ***yt-dlp.exe***. Currently, it fetches the GitHub API page of the latest releases and looks for all things that have a `browser_download_url` (which are the lines with the download links), you need to change that to look for the `yt-dlp.exe` line.

Try:
`for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ('curl -ks https://api.github.com/repos/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest ^| find "yt-dlp.exe"') do (curl -kOL %%B)`

---

The official documented way of [Linking to releases](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/linking-to-releases) is by putting `releases/latest/download/` in the assest link where you usually have `releases/download/{release version number}/`.

So in your case, you can very simply download the file from:
**https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest/download/yt-dlp.exe**

Comment: Why didn't I think of doing that? Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: See my edited edition, certainly a better way to do it

Comment: Now that is simple . I'm updating my script as soon as I get to it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, on Windows 10 you can install the latest version
by using the built-in
[winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/)
like this :

```
winget install yt-dlp
```

To update, run:

```
winget upgrade yt-dlp
```

Source :
[yt-dlp Installation](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/wiki/Installation).

Comment: This would work but it does pose the problem that you can't choose where the program gets installed.

Comment: Winget has the `-l` parameter. See [link](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/201). Note the limitation.